# Div elements move when toggling a certain class. Javascript DOM

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom

So i have an assignment in School where i have to make a "memory" game in javascript. So to hide my flags that im using i made a class called .card which is just a black background place above the flags to hide them. So when a user clicks on the flag i want to toggle the class .card and it will be removed, but when i click a flag i think the class is toggled but the flag is moved behind another flag. I have no idea why this is happening.

Here is the jsfiddle with all the code and so that you can test it out: 
https://jsfiddle.net/L2q63k0p/

```
.card {
    height: 100px;
    width: 150px;
    background-color: black;
    z-index: 10;
    position: absolute;
    opacity: 0.5;
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

Notice that you have to click on the flags "primary" background and not part1 and part2.

I appreciate all the help, also this is my first question so i dont know if i have done everything the way it should. But i hope.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! The full content of your question must be **in** your question, not just linked. Links rot, making the question and its answers useless to people in the future, and people shouldn't have to go off-site to help you. Put a [mcve] **in** the question, ideally using Stack Snippets (the `<>` toolbar button) to make it runnable ([here's how to do one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-do-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do-tha)). More: [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Alright, thanks i will check it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i understand your question correct you want to remove the flag if the answer is correct / the .card class is applied?
If this is the case you should look at the css property [display: none](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/playit.asp?filename=playcss_display&preval=none). To make it a bit more clear what you are doing i would rename your .card to .hidden and only put display `display: none` in.

Comment: As you can see the flags have the class .card on them. But when a user clicks the flag. I want to toggle .card from that flag. Right now i think it works but the flag that is clicked changes position. Thats my problem right now.

Comment: So it sould not change position? Is this the wanted behavior? https://jsfiddle.net/92xnz6cL/

Comment: Hmm i dont think. I got it to work now, by adding a class in css like this.
cardhidden .card{
    display: none;
}
And when a flag is clicked the cardhidden class is added and does this behaviour: https://jsfiddle.net/smw4hjmw/
I don't think its the best solution but its the only way ive got it to work.

Comment: Ah i get it now, only the overlay needed to go. Sorry didn't get it until now.

Comment: No problem:) when you mentioned display: none the idea came to my head. So i marked your answer as helpful or what it is called.